# Error when using regularizers.l1_l2 in 'TimeDistributed(Dense())' layer in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm, regularized

This code runs well,

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(
    LSTM(self.n_neurons, return_sequences=True, use_bias=False, unit_forget_bias=False,
         kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0., stddev=0.01),
         recurrent_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0., stddev=0.01), ),
    input_shape=(self.time_steps, self.input_features),
))
model.add(Dropout(rate=self.dropout_rate))
model.add(TimeDistributed(
    Dense(self.output_features, activation='linear', use_bias=False,
          kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0., stddev=0.01), )
))
```

where `self.n_neurons=64`,`self.input_features=1`,`self.output_features=1`,`self.time_steps=1000`.
The shape of input data is (1, 1000, 1), and the shape of output data is also (1, 1000, 1).

While adding 'regularizers.l1_l2',

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(
    LSTM(self.n_neurons, return_sequences=True, use_bias=False, unit_forget_bias=False,
         kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0., stddev=0.01),
         recurrent_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0., stddev=0.01), ),
    input_shape=(self.time_steps, self.input_features),
))
model.add(Dropout(rate=self.dropout_rate))
model.add(TimeDistributed(
    Dense(self.output_features, activation='linear', use_bias=False,
          kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0., stddev=0.01),
          kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l1_l2(l1=1e-5, l2=1e-4), )
))
```

an error will occur,

```
ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 3 and 0
    From merging shape 0 with other shapes. for '{{node AddN_1}} = AddN[N=2, T=DT_FLOAT](mul_1, AddN)' with input shapes: [1,1000,1], [].
```

I have no idea what happened, can anyone help me? please!

Comment: Can you add the code of how you are training your model?

Comment: `adam=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=adam)`@AloneTogether

Comment: And what is the shape of `self.output_features`?

Comment: `self.output_features` is 1, `self.input_features` is 1, and `self.time_steps` is 1000.

Comment: Already updated.

Comment: The shape of input data is (1, 1000, 1), and the shape of output data is also (1, 1000, 1).